# Jquery Mobile Swipe and click

Tags: jquery, mobile, click, swipe

I am trying to add a next button to my already working swipe code. But it does not do what I want it to do, which is that by clicking it also moves to the next page.
See here part of my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("swipeleft", 'div.ui-page', function(){
        var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition:"slide"}, false, true);
        }
    });
    $(document).on("swiperight", 'div.ui-page', function(){
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
            reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
    });
    $("nextBtn").on("click",function() {
        var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition:"none"}, false, true);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: This is wrong - ($("nextBtn").on("click",function() {) put a (.) or a (#) in front of (nextBtn) depending if you are using a class or an id. even better bind the click to the document like so ($(document).on("click", ". or #/nextBtn", function() { ... )